# How to insert data into sqlite3 database when close or leave a View Controller?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios6

I have already created a table in sqlite3. Now, I want to save the last data display on 'UILabel' when I close or leave 'View Controller' which contains 'UILabel'. How can I do that ?

Comment: add your code in viewWillDisAppear or viewDidDisAppear

Answer (score 1):

There are two functions called when you close or leave your `viewController`

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated; // Called when the view is dismissed, covered or otherwise hidden. Default does nothing
- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated;  // Called after the view was dismissed, covered or otherwise hidden. Default does nothing
```

Hope this helps you..